# cyclonedx is writing to my requirements file

Tags: python

I have installed cyclonedx and I did run it in python
but it is automatically creating or adding things in python requirements.txt file can anyone help me to read a requirements.txt file and then run cyclonedx tool on it and it should not add anything to the file

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like you are not using [Python Virtual Environments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) perhaps to  provide segregation of dependencies between your application and other things (like cyclonedx-python)?

I would normally install CycloneDX Python to my OS (not in a Virtual Environment) as follows:

```
pip install cyclonedx-bom
```

If you have a requirements.txt file, you can then have cyclonedx-bom produce an SBOM based on its contents as follows:

```
cyclonedx-bom -r -i /path/to/requirements.txt -o /path/to/cyclonedx-sbom.xml
```

Note: The above is tested with `cyclonedx-bom` version `3.1.0`.